# Install and run GDBee file geodatabase SQL tool

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, file-geodatabase, pyqt

GDBee is a Python tool for querying file geodatabases using SQL (outside of ArcGIS): https://github.com/AlexArcPy/GDBee

I want to install and run GDBee in Windows 10 (64-bit). As a novice, here's what I tried:

---

I've installed Anaconda Navigator (Anaconda3).

As the GitHub installation instructions imply, I'll check if `PyQt` and `GDAL` are installed in Anaconda.

Go to `Anaconda Navigator` >> `Environments` >> `base (root)`

- I did an "Installed" search for `PyQt`, I see it listed as installed. Good.
- But if I search for `GDAL`, I don't get any results. Not even if I change the search option from "Installed" to "All".

---

I used the GDAL instructions on the Anaconda website: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gdal

In `Anaconda` >> `Environments` >> the arrow to the right of `base(root)` >> `Open Terminal`

Paste in `conda install -c conda-forge gdal` and hit enter. Let it process.

For `Proceed Y/N`, type `y` and hit enter. It finishes.

---

Download the GDBee zip file from the GitHub repo: https://github.com/AlexArcPy/GDBee

Unzip the file and put the resulting folder on the C drive, or somewhere suitable.

The path to the GDB Python script is: `C:\GDBee-master\GDBee-master\src\main.py`.

---

In `Anaconda` >> `Home` >> look for the `Qt Console` PyQt application. Click Launch, which opens the Jupyter QtConsole.

Type `cd "C:\GDBee-master\GDBee-master\src\"`. Hit enter.

Type `run main.py`. Hit enter.

I get an **error**:

```
C:\GDBee-master\GDBee-master\src\geodatabase.py in <module>
      2 """Geodatabase class representing a file geodatabase object."""
      3 
----> 4 import ogr
      5 ogr.UseExceptions()
      6 

**Error:** `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ogr'`.
```

---

I'm stuck at that error. And I'm not sure if I'm headed in the right direction or not.

How can I install and run GDBee?

Answer (score 1):

**Part 1:**

These pages mention the `No module named 'ogr'` problem:

- [No module named 'ogr' in GDAL 3.3.2 installing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/414145/no-module-named-ogr-in-gdal-3-3-2-installing)
- [Cannot run Python scripts with latest in Python 3.9 x64 #180](https://github.com/gisinternals/buildsystem/issues/180)

I searched my C dirve for `ogr.py` and `gdal.py`. In those files, I tried replacing `import ogr` with `import osgeo.ogr`. I did it in `gdal.py` in two places: `C:\Users\<my_user>\anaconda3\pkgs\gdal-3.4.1-py39h9b7a543_0\Lib\site-packages\osgeo`.

But in `ogr.py`, I couldn't find any references to `import ogr`.

I also changed `import ogr` to `import osgeo.ogr` in GDBee: `C:\GDBee-master\GDBee-master\src\geodatabase.py`.

I tried to run GDBee again. It got past the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ogr'` error this time. But now it has a different error:

```
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py in swig_import_helper()
     39                 import traceback
     40                 traceback_string = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info()))
---> 41                 raise ImportError(traceback_string + '\n' + msg)
     42         return importlib.import_module('_gdal')
     43 

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 29, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 565, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1173, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _gdal: The specified module could not be found.

On Windows, with Python >= 3.8, DLLs are no longer imported from the PATH.
If gdalXXX.dll is in the PATH, then set the USE_PATH_FOR_GDAL_PYTHON=YES environment variable
to feed the PATH into os.add_dll_directory().
```

---

**Part 2:**

Regarding the answer from @FelipeGutierrez on this page: [Stack Overflow: No module named ogr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58281021/5576771).

I followed the non-pip instructions in @Felipe‘s option 1.).

> 1.) Download the `Installer for the GDAL python bindings (requires to install the GDAL core)` msi, and install.
>
> Open cmd and type:
>
> ```
> setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL"
> setx PATH "%GDAL_DATA%;C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal-data"
> setx PATH "%GDAL_DRIVER_PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdalplugins"
> ```
>
> *Note that each one of the commands above is a separate one, so copy-paste and enter, each one separately. If you downloaded the x64
> version just remove the (x86).

My steps:

- Downloaded and installed an old version of gdal: `gdal-301-1900-x64-core.msi` from `release-1900-x64-gdal-3-1-4-mapserver-7-6-1` at https://gisinternals.com/query2.html?content=filelist&file=release-1900-x64-gdal-3-1-4-mapserver-7-6-1.zip.
- Opened the terminal in `Anaconda Navigator`. And entered these commands one at a time. I removed  `(x86)` from each line before running.

> ```
> setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\GDAL"
> setx PATH "%GDAL_DATA%;C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal-data"
> setx PATH "%GDAL_DRIVER_PATH%;C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins"
> ```

Now, when I try to run GDBee from `Qt`, it's getting past the previous error.

Now I have a new error:

```
C:\GDBee-master\GDBee-master\src\table.py in <module>
      3 
      4 from collections import OrderedDict
----> 5 import pandas as pd
      6 
      7 from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

---

**Part 3:**

I don’t know why I’m getting that error, since pandas is already installed in Anaconda Navigator.

Just to see what happens, I installed a bunch of other pandas-related libraries in Anaconda Navigator.

- geopandas
- geopandas-base
- pandas-datareader
- pandasql

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loOq0.png).

I restarted Anaconda Navigator and tried to run GDBee again.

Now I get a different error:

```
C:\GDBee-master\GDBee-master\src\geodatabase.py in <module>
      3 
      4 import osgeo.ogr
----> 5 ogr.UseExceptions()
      6 
      7 

NameError: name 'ogr' is not defined
```

---

**Part 4:**

In `C:\GDBee-master\GDBee-master\src\geodatabase.py`, I changed `import osgeo.ogr` to `import osgeo.ogr as ogr`. So that `osgeo.ogr` will be treated as `ogr`.

Now I'm getting the pandas error again.

---

**Part 5:**

I updated pandas in Anaconda Navigator. [Screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyDV3.png)

Previously, when I tried to update pandas, nothing happened. I'd hit Apply, and it would think for a few minutes, but ultimately, nothing changed.

But this time, updating pandas worked. Maybe it was because I installed those other pandas libraries too? Maybe they triggered pandas to get updated properly? I'm not sure.

Anyway, I updated pandas and restarted my computer.

---

**Success:**

Now, when I run GDBee, it loads the GDBee program in PyQT.

And when I browse to a file geodatabase and run a query on it, it works.

[image]

By the way, when it comes to file geodatabases, the WHERE clause in the screenshot works in GDBee, but it doesn't work as an SQL expression in ArcGIS Pro. See: [Clarify the docs: Correlated subqueries not supported in FGDB SQL expressions](https://community.esri.com/t5/data-management-ideas/clarify-the-docs-correlated-subqueries-not/idi-p/1239429).

So that's why I need GDBee: it has much better SQL support for file geodatabases than ArcGIS does.

Alternatively, it looks like there is a similar paid product here: https://sql4arc.com/ by Manifold (untested).

Comment: When you finally get a different error message: https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/vudpu8/tries_to_fix_error_gets_the_old_error_message_back/